# How do I find a document using its id and modify the value of a header? I want to do this for multiple headers

Tags: mongodb, nosql

So my MongoDB database contains more than 250 entries. I want to find specific documents within the database, and modify content within that document.

For instance,

```
{"_id":"0001"
 "information":"apple"}

{"_id":"0002"
 "information":"banana"}

{"_id":"0003"
 "information":"orange"}
```

I want to find documents with id 0001 and 0003, and show the content of information as :

```
{"_id":"0001"
 "information":"apple, cat"}

{"_id":"00002"
 "information":"banana"}

{"_id":"0003"
 "information":"orange, cat"}
```

Comment: where from the `cat` is coming? from some other field?

Comment: @SaikatChakrabortty, it is entered manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A key cannot have multiple values unless its an array field. You'll have to maintain the 'information' field as array

Use the below query:

`db.coll.update({"_id":"0003"}, {$addToSet: {"information": "cat"} })`

Comment: Ah, yes, my bad. It's an array. The query you provided is for one id. How do I do this for multiple documents? For example, what if I want to add cat or any other value to documents with ids 0004, 0005, and 0006?

Comment: Is there an common field in those documents? If yes, use it as filter parameter